# How to manually align, change size, and add scroll pane of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, jscrollpane

I am creating a `JTable` in Netbeans and am having three minor issues with the structure.

1. I can't seem to align my table in the direction I want (Say North, East, South, or West) and now it's annoyingly hovering over my JButton.
2. The code I wrote to set the dimensions of the JTable do nothing if I change the variables.
3. The code I wrote to add a JScrollPane is not showing up when I run it.

I understand if you can't solve all three but I figured I'd put them all in one instead of three different questions so any help with a problem is appreciated!

**Also as a note, ignore everything after the `ActionListener`. I am eventually going to make the code read a text file and sort that data in an `ArrayList`. Then somehow into the table instead of how I manually set it up in this example.

Here is my code (problem areas are labeled in comments in bold, capitalized font):

Main:

```
package libraryinventory;
 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {

    static String[] bookArray;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        GUICommandFunctions guiDemo = new GUICommandFunctions();
        //What to do when window closes
        guiDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // size of window in pixels
        guiDemo.setSize(1000, 720); 
        //make window visible
        guiDemo.setVisible(true);
        
    }
        
}
```

GUI Class:

```
package libraryinventory;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.Box;
import static javax.swing.Box.createHorizontalBox;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class GUICommandFunctions extends JFrame {
    
    private JButton ButtonOne;
    private JTable jt;
    
    public GUICommandFunctions() { 
        
        this.setTitle("Library Inventory"); //Name of window
     
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();  
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Location of panel for JButton

        ButtonOne = LibraryContentButton();
        panel.add(ButtonOne); //adding panel to JFrame

        
        String[] columns = {"Title", "Author/Language", "Publisher", "Page Count", "Version Number/Genre/Topic", "Part of a series/Illustrator"}; //columns of the JTable
        String[][] data = {{"The Keto Cookbook", "Chronicle Books", "304", "English", "Keto Cooking", "null"}, //data under the columns
                           {"The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", "Del Rey", "224", "Douglas Adams", "Fantasy", "Y"}      
        };
        
        jt = new JTable(data, columns){ //Makes it so can't edit data inside table once ran
            public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns) {
                    return false;
            }
        };
        
        jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 63)); //Set size. **HERE IS PROBLEM #2**
        jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true); //Set visible
        jt.setVerticalAlignment(JTable.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT); //**HERE IS PROBLEM #1**
        
        JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt); //add scroll **HERE IS PROBLEM #3**
        add(jps);
        
    }
    
        private JButton LibraryContentButton() { //
            JButton content = new JButton("Click to view all content");
            content.setFocusable(false);
            content.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            content.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            content.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            content.setToolTipText("Shows content of the entire library in a neatly ordered JTable");
            content.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 75));

            
            
            content.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Eventually will make this button load up the JTable");              
                }
            });
            return content;
     
        }

    static {
    
        int arrayCount;
      
        FileReader fr = null;
        
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mark Case\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LibraryInventory\\src\\libraryinventory\\library.txt"); //Reads in text file
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUICommandFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);       
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = "";
        arrayCount = 0;
        try {
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                str.add(line);
                arrayCount = arrayCount + 1;
                
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUICommandFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Here we would actually set the type to what the user wants (note: Set it to a "0" if the user wants all Books)
        String selType = "2";  
        
        // Call method to select Books by category type
        String methodResult = SelectType(str, arrayCount, selType);
        
    }  

    private static String SelectType (ArrayList<String> str, int arrayCount, String selType) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayCount; i++) {
           
            String buffer = str.get(i);
            String bookCat = buffer.substring(0,1);
            
            // Print books by Category - "0" type means print all Books
            if (selType.equals(bookCat)) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }          
            else if (selType.equals("0")) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }
        }
        return "0";   
    }



}
```

Comment: `new JPanel();` uses a `FlowLayout` by default; `add(jps);` is adding the `JScrollPane` to the "default" layout position, which is `CENTER` for `BorderLayout`, so you now have two components occupying the centre position, which `BorderLayout` does not support.  `JTable` has no `setVerticalAlignment`  method, not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's take a quick look at the constructor...

```
public GUICommandFunctions() { 
    //...
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();  
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Location of panel for JButton

    ButtonOne = LibraryContentButton();
    panel.add(ButtonOne); //adding panel to JFrame
    //...
    jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 63)); //Set size. **HERE IS PROBLEM #2**
    jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true); //Set visible
    jt.setVerticalAlignment(JTable.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT); //**HERE IS PROBLEM #1**
    
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt); //add scroll **HERE IS PROBLEM #3**
    add(jps);
}
```

You add `panel` to the `CENTER`.  Since you've extended directly from `JFrame`, the layout is already `BorderLayout`, so this is fine.

But then you add `jps` using `add(jps);`, which will add the component to the layouts default position, which in the case of `BorderLayout` is `CENTER`.  This is problematic, as `BorderLayout` only allows a single component to be managed at each position, which explains why you're `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize` isn't working, as the `BorderLayout` is ignoring it, and making the component fill the available space in the `CENTER`

So, I modified your code.  First, I extended from `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`.  It's generally discouraged to extend from `JFrame` directly, you're not adding any new functionality to the class, locking yourself into a single use case and it generally just makes you live more difficult.

Secondly, I placed the `JScrollPane` at the `SOUTH` position of the `BorderLayout`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GUICommandFunctionsPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GUICommandFunctionsPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton ButtonOne;
        private JTable jt;

        public GUICommandFunctionsPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Location of panel for JButton

            ButtonOne = LibraryContentButton();
            panel.add(ButtonOne); //adding panel to JFrame

            String[] columns = {"Title", "Author/Language", "Publisher", "Page Count", "Version Number/Genre/Topic", "Part of a series/Illustrator"}; //columns of the JTable
            String[][] data = {{"The Keto Cookbook", "Chronicle Books", "304", "English", "Keto Cooking", "null"}, //data under the columns
            {"The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", "Del Rey", "224", "Douglas Adams", "Fantasy", "Y"}
            };

            jt = new JTable(data, columns) { //Makes it so can't edit data inside table once ran
                public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns) {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 63)); //Set size. **HERE IS PROBLEM #2**
            jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true); //Set visible

            JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt);
            add(jps, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

        private JButton LibraryContentButton() { //
            JButton content = new JButton("Click to view all content");
            content.setFocusable(false);
            content.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            content.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            content.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            content.setToolTipText("Shows content of the entire library in a neatly ordered JTable");
            content.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 75));

            content.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GUICommandFunctionsPane.this, "Eventually will make this button load up the JTable");
                }
            });
            return content;

        }

//        static {
//
//            int arrayCount;
//
//            FileReader fr = null;
//
//            try {
//                fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mark Case\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LibraryInventory\\src\\libraryinventory\\library.txt"); //Reads in text file
//            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
//                Logger.getLogger(GUICommandFunctionsPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//            }
//
//            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
//            ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
//            String line = "";
//            arrayCount = 0;
//            try {
//                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                    str.add(line);
//                    arrayCount = arrayCount + 1;
//
//                }
//            } catch (IOException ex) {
//                Logger.getLogger(GUICommandFunctionsPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//            }
//
//            // Here we would actually set the type to what the user wants (note: Set it to a "0" if the user wants all Books)
//            String selType = "2";
//
//            // Call method to select Books by category type
//            String methodResult = SelectType(str, arrayCount, selType);
//
//        }
//
//        private static String SelectType(ArrayList<String> str, int arrayCount, String selType) {
//            for (int i = 1; i < arrayCount; i++) {
//
//                String buffer = str.get(i);
//                String bookCat = buffer.substring(0, 1);
//
//                // Print books by Category - "0" type means print all Books
//                if (selType.equals(bookCat)) {
//                    System.out.println(buffer);
//                } else if (selType.equals("0")) {
//                    System.out.println(buffer);
//                }
//            }
//            return "0";
//        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and I would discourage you from using a `static` initialiser this way, instead, this either needs to go into the constructor, or, you should use some form of dependency injection to pass the information to the class

Comment: Thank you! I added a setSize in the main since it was to small to display the whole table. Once I was able to edit the size of the table the JScrollPane came right up!

Comment: @Chalki471 `setSize` is the wrong approach, as it needs to take into account the window decorations, which are different on different platforms (and even different on the same platform across different devices) - focus on the providing better sizing hints